# Soc in MVC which is the better design pattern for mvc for huge distributed applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to create a E-commerce application ,Which is the best design
model
I have seen some of them are separating Entity framework context
class in Seperate class library and Business layer in seperate class
library  and Data Classes poco class in seperate Class library
project. 
 We have context class know consider the example

This is Db created Poco class

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Web.Mvc;  
 public partial class User   { 
 public int UserID { get; set; } 
 public string Username { get; set; }   
 public string Password { get; set; }
 public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }  
 public string FullName
    { get; set; }         
 public string EmailID { get; set; }
                }  [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Register(User U)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                    {
                        dc.Users.Add(U);
                        dc.SaveChanges();
                        ModelState.Clear();
                        U = null;
                        ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
                    }
                }
                return View(U);
            }
```

or else i have to create a seperate class container for that and access?

```
 public class User   {  
    public int UserID { get; set; } 
    public string Username { get; set; }   
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }  
    public string FullName  { get; set; }  *
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
                        }
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult Register(User U)
            {              
                    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                    {
                          User.UserID= u.UserID;
                        User.Username = u.Username;
                         User. Password = u.Password;
                        User.ConfirmPassword = u.ConfirmPassword;
                       User.UserID= u.UserID;                     
                        dc.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
                    }
                }
                return View(U);
            }
```

which is better way and what is the difference between model binding and these?
Why we are not preferred binding with EF classes?

Answer (score 0):

Second way - when you separate your **DAL** (Data Access Layer) and `ViewModels` that Bind in `Controller` automatically by MVC is better.

Because if you separate atleast this 2 layers (I can't see **BL** layer in your example) you now can easily change your `Views` where you show User Information and don't mess with your **DAL** layer, but change your mappings (You map your `ViewModel` in `Register` `Controller`).

This could looks ***insignificant if you have really simple View and DAL logic***, but when your project will grow it will be good, because ***this will allow you to change View Logic and DAL logic separately***.